Error in SJML while compiling a dis property
I'm trying to compile a sjml file and it throws a error.
SJML: ERR Failed to compile.
/Users/Brent/Desktop/SJML_Project/app.sjml Ln 11: Invalid datastructure
Run sjml comp -log to see the Log file
Please Help
I've tried changing the sjml version But it didn't work. Indentation is also correct and it doesn't show any errors in SJML 3.0
app.sjml
   window: "Native"; 
   icon: "icns.ico"; 
   ver: 2.0.10 ; 

dis: "Main";
break(4);
    formation = clean.head ;

sjml.compile(Data == none)

